# kernel BUG at drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/netdev.c:3804!

Tags: debian, networking, kernel, drivers, crash

Our server started to crash almost each day when the traffic is higher during the peak hours, the syslog is always spammed by a few eth0 resets and then the network crashes completely and the machine has to be rebooted in order to gain remote access to the machine again.

Does this error mean that the NIC card is dead or is it just a software issue ?

Running kernel: 4.19.0-10-amd64
OS: Debian 10

```
Jan 25 18:00:41 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [161879.702795] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Reset adapter unexpectedly
    Jan 25 18:00:45 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [161883.545928] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
    Jan 25 18:04:41 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162119.835193] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Reset adapter unexpectedly
    Jan 25 18:04:45 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162123.214074] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
    Jan 25 18:05:50 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162188.695254] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Reset adapter unexpectedly
    Jan 25 18:05:54 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162192.610229] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
    Jan 25 18:06:14 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162212.759251] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Reset adapter unexpectedly
    Jan 25 18:06:18 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162216.990139] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
    Jan 25 18:07:27 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162285.975361] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Reset adapter unexpectedly
    Jan 25 18:07:31 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162289.814340] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
    Jan 25 18:07:47 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162305.687558] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Reset adapter unexpectedly
    Jan 25 18:07:51 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162309.506389] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
    Jan 25 18:07:59 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal systemd[1]: session-247.scope: Succeeded.
    Jan 25 18:08:48 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162366.871583] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Reset adapter unexpectedly
    Jan 25 18:08:52 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162370.734613] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
    Jan 25 18:09:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal CRON[27975]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean)
    Jan 25 18:09:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal CRON[27974]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
    Jan 25 18:09:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
    Jan 25 18:09:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
    Jan 25 18:09:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
    Jan 25 18:09:42 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162420.891568] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Reset adapter unexpectedly
    Jan 25 18:09:46 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162424.734698] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
    Jan 25 18:10:57 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162495.895693] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Reset adapter unexpectedly
    Jan 25 18:11:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162499.750608] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.895786] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Reset adapter unexpectedly
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.915877] ------------[ cut here ]------------
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.915964] kernel BUG at drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/netdev.c:3804!
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.916048] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.916126] CPU: 0 PID: 5 Comm: kworker/0:0 Tainted: G        W         4.19.0-10-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.132-1
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.916222] Hardware name: FUJITSU D3401-H1/D3401-H1, BIOS V5.0.0.11 R1.7.0.SR.2 for D3401-H1x                11/25/2015
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.916328] Workqueue: events e1000_reset_task [e1000e]
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.916410] RIP: 0010:e1000_flush_desc_rings+0x2a9/0x2f0 [e1000e]
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.916486] Code: ff ff 31 c0 31 ed 66 41 89 45 20 e9 a8 fe ff ff 4c 89 e7 e8 89 f3 ff ff e9 af fe ff ff 4c 89 e7 e8 7c f3 ff ff e9 30 fe ff ff <0f> 0b 4c 89 e7 e8 6d f3 ff ff eb ac 4c 89 e7 e8 63 f3 ff ff e9 68
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.916615] RSP: 0018:ffffaf708629fde0 EFLAGS: 00010202
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.916689] RAX: 0000000000000067 RBX: ffff9043211f48c0 RCX: 000000000000007d
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.916780] RDX: 0000000000000067 RSI: 0000000000000246 RDI: 0000000000000246
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.916872] RBP: 000000003103f0fa R08: 0000000000000002 R09: ffffaf708629fdc4
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.916963] R10: 00000000000000fe R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff9043211f4e38
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.917055] R13: ffff90432a33f800 R14: 0000000004008000 R15: ffff9043211f4940
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.917147] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff904331200000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.917240] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.917315] CR2: 00007f31849487f8 CR3: 00000005a660a003 CR4: 00000000003606f0
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.917406] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.917497] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.917588] Call Trace:
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.917663]  e1000e_reset+0x574/0x790 [e1000e]
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.917743]  e1000e_down+0x1cf/0x200 [e1000e]
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.917819]  e1000e_reinit_locked+0x46/0x60 [e1000e]
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.917898]  process_one_work+0x1a7/0x3a0
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.917974]  worker_thread+0x30/0x390
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.918046]  ? create_worker+0x1a0/0x1a0
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.918118]  kthread+0x112/0x130
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.918188]  ? kthread_bind+0x30/0x30
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.918260]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.918331] Modules linked in: unix_diag ip6t_rpfilter ipt_rpfilter binfmt_misc veth ip6t_MASQUERADE ipt_MASQUERADE xt_CHECKSUM xt_comment xt_tcpudp bridge stp llc dm_mod ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_raw ip6table_mangle ip6table_nat nf_nat_ipv6 ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_raw iptable_mangle iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_filter nf_tables nfnetlink cpufreq_conservative cpufreq_userspace cpufreq_powersave fuse intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul evdev crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel intel_cstate intel_uncore squashfs iTCO_wdt pcc_cpufreq sg iTCO_vendor_support intel_pch_thermal intel_rapl_perf fujitsu_laptop wmi loop sparse_keymap video acpi_pad button ip_tables x_tables autofs4
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.918698]  ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic fscrypto ecb btrfs zstd_decompress zstd_compress xxhash raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid0 multipath linear raid1 md_mod sd_mod crc32c_intel ahci xhci_pci libahci xhci_hcd libata aesni_intel e1000e usbcore scsi_mod aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper i2c_i801 usb_common thermal fan
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.918920] ---[ end trace fc8f12793b39335d ]---
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.918998] RIP: 0010:e1000_flush_desc_rings+0x2a9/0x2f0 [e1000e]
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.919078] Code: ff ff 31 c0 31 ed 66 41 89 45 20 e9 a8 fe ff ff 4c 89 e7 e8 89 f3 ff ff e9 af fe ff ff 4c 89 e7 e8 7c f3 ff ff e9 30 fe ff ff <0f> 0b 4c 89 e7 e8 6d f3 ff ff eb ac 4c 89 e7 e8 63 f3 ff ff e9 68
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.919206] RSP: 0018:ffffaf708629fde0 EFLAGS: 00010202
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.919281] RAX: 0000000000000067 RBX: ffff9043211f48c0 RCX: 000000000000007d
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.919372] RDX: 0000000000000067 RSI: 0000000000000246 RDI: 0000000000000246
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.919464] RBP: 000000003103f0fa R08: 0000000000000002 R09: ffffaf708629fdc4
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.919555] R10: 00000000000000fe R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff9043211f4e38
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.919647] R13: ffff90432a33f800 R14: 0000000004008000 R15: ffff9043211f4940
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.919739] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff904331200000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.919851] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.919937] CR2: 00007f31849487f8 CR3: 00000005a660a003 CR4: 00000000003606f0
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.920030] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
    Jan 25 18:12:01 Debian-83-jessie-64-minimal kernel: [162559.920123] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kernel bug causes ethernet driver to stop working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424568/kernel-bug-causes-ethernet-driver-to-stop-working) The hardware model seems to match exactly, and the call trace looks very similar.

Comment: That topic is very old, I have much newer kernel and I would rather have answer with current updated information if someone has some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kernel BUG at drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/netdev.c:3804!
kernel: [162559.916048] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
kernel: [162559.916126] CPU: 0 PID: 5 Comm: kworker/0:0 Tainted: G        W         4.19.0-10-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.132-1
kernel: [162559.916222] Hardware name: FUJITSU D3401-H1/D3401-H1, BIOS V5.0.0.11 R1.7.0.SR.2 for D3401-H1x                11/25/2015
kernel: [162559.916328] Workqueue: events e1000_reset_task [e1000e]
kernel: [162559.916410] RIP: 0010:e1000_flush_desc_rings+0x2a9/0x2f0 [e1000e]
```

You're running Debian's distribution kernel, which has some patches applied on top of the upstream source, so my quick analysis might not be entirely accurate. But looking at [line 3804 of `drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/netdev.c` in 4.19.170 upstream source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/netdev.c?h=v4.19.170#n3804) brings us to this line:

```
BUG_ON(tdt != tx_ring->next_to_use);
```

This would trigger the `kernel BUG at...` message with the stack trace and all that stuff if the specified condition is true.

That line is in function `e1000_flush_tx_ring()`, which is called by function `e1000_flush_desc_rings()` which in turn is mentioned as the instruction pointer location in the bug message:

```
RIP: 0010:e1000_flush_desc_rings+0x2a9/0x2f0 [e1000e]
```

Perhaps the compiler has inlined or otherwise optimized the `e1000_flush_tx_ring()` function so that it is not apparent as an identifiable symbol for the `RIP:` line. But it seems to match: the call trace strongly suggests that the driver was in the process of resetting the NIC, and flushing the TX ring is clearly part of that process.

But what makes the reset necessary? It turns out that [Intel has published a specification update for the I218/I219 NICs](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/design/products-and-solutions/networking-and-io/ethernet-connection-i218/technical-library.html?grouping=EMT_Content%20Type&sort=title:asc).

> 5.Buffer Overrun While the I219 is Processing DMA Transactions
>
> Problem:Intel® 100/200 Series Chipset platforms reduced the round-trip latency for the LAN Controller DMA accesses, causing in some high-performance cases a buffer overrun while the I219 LAN Connected Device is processing the DMA transactions.
>
> Implication:I219LM and I219V devices can fall into unrecovered Tx hang under very stressfully UDP traffic and multiple reconnection of Ethernet cable. This Tx hang of the LAN Controller is only recovered if the system is rebooted.
>
> Workaround:Slightly slow down DMA access by reducing the number of outstanding requests.This workaround could have an impact on TCP traffic performance and could reduce performance up to 5 to    15% (depending) on the platform. Disabling TSO eliminates performance loss for TCP traffic without a noticeable impact on CPU performance.
>
> Status: Intel® 100/200 Series Chipsets – NoFix
>
> Intel® 300 Series Chipsets - Fixed

So the root cause seems to be a hardware (or possibly NIC firmware) bug. The driver finds that the structure of the TX ring buffer has been corrupted, and assumes the cause is a fault in the driver. But in this case, it seems the fault is in the NIC itself.

The recommended workaround is to disable the TCP Segmentation Offload feature (`tso`) of the NIC:

```
ethtool -K eth0 tso off
```

The Fujitsu D3401-H1 seems to have a Intel Core i7-6700 processor, which is of the Skylake generation... so I would expect the Intel 100 series chipset along with it. It looks like there is no fix available for that chipset, and so you'll probably need to apply the workaround.